# JDBC connection string with instance name and domain

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have a database created in SQL Server with the following configuration:

Also, I am trying to connect to the database named `EDS`.

For that I created the following details:

Should i have domain in the string or should it be in the username?
When i go to the database properties i see the owner has.
Also, is the url correct on the instance part according to the image? it looks like it is not able to go to that particular instance.

Also, this is the configuration for the connection (using Windows Authenticaton)

When I put  in the username I am getting the following error log:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user '. ClientConnectionId:e812971f-b03c-4210-9dbd-de0791bcc304

Comment: If you want to connect using the instance name then you should not include a port number because the SQL Browser service will figure that out for you. Also, chances are good that a SQL Express instance is *not* listening on port 1433. (By default, SQL Express instances listen on an arbitrary port number up in the 40000+ range.)

Comment: I configured the SQLEXPRESS01 to listen on that port. So i should remove the instance on the connection string and use only the port? makes sense @GordThompson

Comment: If you've configured for port 1433 yourself then yes, just host name and port number should be all you need.

Comment: If you want to log into the SQL Server with your Windows credentials then you would add `;integratedSecurity=true` to your connection URL and not bother passing a username and password.

Comment: @GordThompson i am getting that the driver does not support such authentication but i am using sqljdbc42 which is the latest..

Comment: Make sure that your application can find the appropriate (i.e., 32-bit or 64-bit) sqljdbc_auth.dll file required for Integrated Authentication on Windows. That is, "copy the sqljdbc_auth.dll file to a directory on the Windows system path on the computer where the JDBC driver is installed". For more details, look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx#Connectingintegrated).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When specifying the location of the SQL Server instance, one normally provides `serverName\instanceName` **or** `serverName:portNumber`, not both. That is, either

```
jdbc:sqlserver://INNOWAVE-99\SQLEXPRESS01;databaseName=EDS
```

or

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=EDS
```

(assuming that the SQLEXPRESS01 instance has been explicitly configured to listen on port 1433, which is not usually the case for a SQL Express instance).

As mentioned in the documentation for [Building the Connection URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx)

> If both a portNumber and instanceName are used, the portNumber will take precedence and the instanceName will be ignored.

There is no `domain=` property defined for the connection URL for Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server. Logging in to the SQL Server instance with Windows domain credentials is done implicitly using the `integratedSecurity=true` connection property (and *not* explicitly providing a username and password); details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx#Connectingintegrated).

Comment: Thanks, removing the port number got it to work for me (in Spotfire).

Comment: Removing the portNumber worked also in Payara Connection Pool definition. Thank you.

Comment: has anyone tried connection with sql server express using spark?

Comment: Don't foreget jdbc:sqlserver://192.169.52.105\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=icamdbstore the double  slash if you're in springboot application.properties

Comment: Is there a similar way to generate jdbc url for SQL Table generated through AWS RDS?

Comment: If you are using Azure sql edge on local machine, use `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=<DB_NAME>;encrypt=false`

Comment: This is also the case in Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) tool aka Kettle

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having the same problem. Working for me too without port number.
Don't forget to give semicolon at the end of the connection.

**Connect to the default database on the local computer by using integrated authentication:**

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;
```

**Connect to a named database on a remote server:**

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

**Connect on the default port to the remote server:**

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

**Connect by specifying a customized application name:**

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=MyApp;
```

Reference Link : [mssql document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I don't agree with you. I have just removed the trailing semicolon and my problem disappeared.