# Knowage BI - SQL Server DataSource

Tags: mssql-jdbc, fiware-knowage

I have a question about knowage (opensource BI software - www.knowage-suite.com).

Can anyone tell me how create DataSource with a SQL Server connection?

Regards, 
Tomasz

Comment: I googled and found the manual here: http://download.forge.ow2.org/knowage/Knowage_6.x_CE_Manual.pdf. It says you can create JDBC or JNDI (?) connections. So you need to plug in an JDBC SQL server connection string. There are some samples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820087/jdbc-connection-string-with-instance-name-and-domain Please try this and edit your question with any new information including error messages

Answer (score 1):

```
0> put MSSQL JDBC driver into `./<your_knowage_installation_directory>/lib` folder

1> log in (on web-UI) as administrator  
2> data source  
3> click on red '+' sign  
4> give a label and choose your dialect (SQL-Server)
5> fill your credential (need SQLSErver auth, not active directory)
6> insert into JDBC this: `jdbc:sqlserver://<YOUR_SERVER_IP>`  
7> insert `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` as driver

8> create your dataset as a query (remember `use <your_db_name>` at the beginning of your query)
```

[link to MSSQL jdbc drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score -1):

Below are given steps for installing Knowage and setting up DB.

**Install MySQL**
1.
                sudo apt-get install mysql-server

2.
                Modified /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and changed 
                from

```
            bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 
            to
            bind-address            = *
```

3.
                mysql -u root -p

```
            ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ''mypswd ';
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY ''mypswd';
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
            service mysql restart
```

**Install Java**

```
            sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
            sudo apt-get update
            sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
            sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default 

            export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
            export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**Install Knowage**
1. Download Knowage

```
            wget http://download.forge.ow2.org/knowage/Knowage-6_2_0-RC-CE-Installer-Unix-20180509.zip
            unzip Knowage-6_2_0-RC-CE-Installer-Unix-20180509.zip
```

2. Create Swap Memory (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04)

```
            sudo swapon --show
            free -h
            df -h
            sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
            ls -lh /swapfile
            sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
            ls -lh /swapfile
            sudo mkswap /swapfile
            sudo swapon /swapfile
            sudo swapon --show
            free -h
```

3. Setup Knowage

   ```
           sh Knowage-6_2_0-RC-CE-Installer-Unix-20180509.sh -c 


           Used existing MySQL DB and it created knowage_ce with following tables.
   ```
4. Add Database Source in conf/server.xml

   ```
           <Resource name="jdbc/knowage" auth="Container"
     type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
     driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/knowage_ce"
     username="root"
     password="mypswd" 
     maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
     maxWait="-1"/>
   ```
5. Download MySQL Connector and copy to lib dir

   ```
           cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar /home/babbarkrishan/knowage/Knowage-Server-CE/lib/
   ```
6. start the knowage server in /bin

   ```
           sh startup.sh
   ```

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Regards,

Krishan

Comment: Question is about how to add data source for Microsoft SQL Server, here you are talking about installation process for it with MySQL