# SonarQube 7.2.1 - Connect to SQL Server (Mutiple Instances)

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube

I am working with Sonarqube 7.2.1 and SQL Server 2016 Always ON (in a different server). I am running  multiple instances (SQL Server)  in the same server.

So my question is this: to connect Sonarqube to the SQL Server Database I desire can I still use this connection string:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server_hostname_or_IP;databaseName=sonar
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=mypassword
```

Or do I have to user a different one?

Comment: Do not store your password in the configuration file. Use integrated login. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) to get more information about the connection string.

Comment: I've tried but without success.  I also tried like this: sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server_hostname_or_IP:port;databaseName=sonar
But I am still getting errors. I tried making a connection with a UDL file with this credentials and hostname and it works ok. Although, with SonerQube it's not working.

Comment: Can you give me further assistance regarding this issue please? Maybe how to do it using integrated login.

Comment: I am getting this error: "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection reset ClientConnectionId:f1473004-ce68-43fa-ad81-b185b86b7ccb)"

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/) that contains a  step-by-step instruction. Do not overlook this: "If you want to use integrated security, you have to download the Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver 6.2 package"

Comment: I checked it. whithout Integrated 
Security. And I still haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820087/jdbc-connection-string-with-instance-name-and-domain) SO question could help

Comment: I managed to do it whithout using "Integrated Security". I had everything working ok. I believe it was some network issue...

Answer (score 0):

you need to use registered listener name (hostname) of your always on database.

You cannot fallback/switch to failover node with IP address.

Other parameters can remain same. the only thing is the sonarqube user is needed to be defined on both nodes with appropriate database permissions.

I also aggree on using integrated security, however it is your choice to have it or not.