# Informatica installation using SQL Server Database(windows authentication)

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-authentication, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to install Informatica server . I am using SQL Express database and windows Authentication.
I am able to connect to database using SSMS.

But when I try to give database details in Domain Configuration repository database information, I get below error.

I got the host name and service name details by running below queries in SSMS.

```
SELECT HOST_NAME() AS HostName
select @@SERVICENAME
```

Can someone please assist with this.

[image]

Comment: looking at the host name.. looks like it is installed on your desktop.. what if you use LOCALHOST as hostname?

Comment: I get the same error when I use localhost as Host Name.

Comment: have you had a look at this to see if you can use a custom connection string instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820087/jdbc-connection-string-with-instance-name-and-domain

Comment: or how about using the following for the connection string? jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=SQLEXPRESS
com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Comment: I tried using jdbc:informatica:sqlserver://localhost:1433;SelectMethod=cursor;DatabaseName=SQLEXPRESS                      since this format automatically comes when I click on Custom JDBC string and replaces host details and port number but same error

Answer (score 0):

The Database Service Name should be given is the Database you created for Informatica in SQL server.

Comment: could you pls add more details - like screenshot etc.